# How to search on contents of a referenced field in morphia

Tags: mongodb, morphia

Lets say that I have classes like this:

```
public class Foo{
  @id
  ObjectID id;
  @Reference
  Bar bar;
  long fooValue;
}

public class Bar {
  @id
  ObjectID id;
  @Reference
  Baz baz;
  long barValue;
}

public class baz{
  @id
  ObjectID 
  String content;
}
```

If I want to load all foo objects in which the referenced baz has a certain value what syntax should I use?  Lets see I want all foo in which the referenced baz.content value is "foobar" how can I do it?  Would it be quicker to work backwards by looking up all baz and then finding all bar that reference it etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work (well) with MongoDB. What you are trying to do is a JOIN, which doesn't exist.

What you can do is:

1. Query `Baz`, which gets you a `Baz.ObjectId` (for each match).
2. Query the `Bar` that references the `Baz.ObjectId`, which gets you a `Bar.ObjectId`
3. Do the same for `Foo` referencing the `Bar.ObjectId`

So for each matched document in `Baz` you'll need two more queries to get its `Foo`.

Could you embed `Baz` into `Bar` and `Bar` into `Foo`? Then you'd only need a single query.